# mulitple same username but differ in passwords in Joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

having multiple and same username but differ in their passwords is this possible in joomla?
if yes, how can I do that.

```
e.g
username | password
one        123
one        456
one        789
```

thanks
..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's not possible to use same username with different password in `Joomla`.

Answer (score 2):

Joomla!'s user model requires a unique identity (i.e. unique username per user).

This is a fundamental aspect of access control: 1 unique user identity for each user.

You could conceivably create an extension for Joomla! that would simulate what you're trying to achieve by making a unique identity from the combination of username and password. Of course, that would either have to prevent users from changing their password or provide a complex mechanism that made sure the hash of their new password didn't conflict with another user of the same username.

Of course rejecting such a password attempt would reveal the details of another users account access...